# Calculating a value difference between a transactions and its prior transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL and need some advice on how to construct a query.  Essentially I have file of fuel transactions (credit card swipes) and within it the current odometer reading is captured.  I am trying to construct a query using the vehicle number (unique id for the vehicle), the transaction date, and the current odometer reading to calculate a new column that looks at a given fuel transaction, finds the prior transaction (based on transaction date) for that vehicle transaction and then calculates the miles that were driven between the two data points.

I am struggling with identifying the prior transaction.  Any help would be appreciated to help me get started. I am not looking for the specific script, but just some pseudo code would help get me going.

If you want to get specific, here are the key columns.  CompanyVehicleNumber, TransactionDate(format YYYYMMDD), TransactionTime(format HHMMSS), Odometer (e.g. 123456)

Thanks.

Comment: create a sqlfiddle.............

Comment: What's the data type for `TransactionDate` and `TransactionTime`?

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that.  All of those fields mentioned are strings (nvarchar)

Comment: What you want is easy. Seriously, easy. However, if you want to use dates and times in any kind of comparison or computation, do not -- wait, let me rephrase -- DO NOT EVER keep dates and times either a) separated into a date field and time field or b) in any other type other than native date types (datetime, timestamp, etc.). You have a very serious problem, and your inability to find the prior transaction is the symptom, not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` to get the previous transaction:

```
SELECT
    t.*, MilesDiff = t.odometer - x.odometer
FROM tbl t
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 odometer
    FROM tbl
    WHERE
        CompanyVehicleNumber = t.CompanyVehicleNumber
        AND (TransactionDate + TransactionTime) < (t.TransactionDate + t.TransactionTime)
    ORDER BY (TransactionDate + TransactionTime) DESC
) x(odometer)
```

Note here that you need to convert the `TransactionDate` and `TransactionTime` to a `DATETIME` to be able to compare the transactions.

---

Here is one way to convert dates and times:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(8) = '20130101'
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(6) = '053000'

SELECT
    CAST(@date AS DATETIME) + 
    CAST(LEFT(@time, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@time, 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(@time, 2) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Awesome, that is what I was looking for but couldn't put it together in my head.. been a long day.  I should be able to get there with this as a starting point.  I'll reply back if I encounter any issues.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added `DESC` in the `ORDER BY`.